# Error with building a project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After downloading all the gradle files and the jcenter.bintray.com files, I tried to run my project and got this error message.
What does it mean?

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:20.1+.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/
>        Required by:
>            Application1:app:unspecified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using the SDK Manager to download the latest Android Support library.

You might also have to adjust the protect settings. (I don't know about the Maven part.)

If you open the build files (build.gradle when using gradle), Android Studio will highlight warnings and errors. Hover over those for info on how to fix the problems.

Comment: Turns out, I had to install the support library and everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error these days, for me changing the `buildToolsVersion` in `build.gradle(app)` solved the problem.

Try `buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"` or `buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"`